# Limit analysis for binomial series raised to 0 < fractional exponent < 1

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I am trying to expand a series and trying to find a limit analysis:

(1+x)^a

where 0 < a < 1.

I understand that a possible expansion is:

1 + ax + a(a-1)(x^2)/(2!) + a(a-1)(a-2)(x^3)/(3!) +...

What about for fractional values of a? How can I find the limits for which a is for a particular number 0 < a < 1?

Comment: expansion remains the some , but it becomes an infinite expansion , (for natural numbers it does not happen as after some terms , remaining become $0$)

Comment: We generally neglect higher terms

Comment: @avz2611 I see, which terms onwards should I neglect? say power = 2 onwards? how to decide?

Comment: @Archis any idea?

Comment: When $a-2$ arrives those terms become 0

Comment: meaning to say, i could ignore x^3 onwards?